# What kind of prompt do I need in order to run groovyscripts?

Tags: groovy

In my new job my predecessor automated a number of tasks using groovyscript. I know absolutely nothing about this system (I mostly code in R, SAS, SQL etc) and I'm having trouble following the documentation, which looks something like this:

[image]

This seems to imply I should be using a prompt of some kind (powerwhell or similar). Exactly what type of prompt should I be using in order to run these types of commands?

I know groovyscript is somehow connected to Java, and so I tried to open the local Java installation, hoping a suitable prompt would appear. Alas, all I saw was a blackscreen activating for 0.3 seconds before disapperaring.

Comment: 1st - there is nothing about groovy above. 2nd - i guess you are on windows - if so, run cmd then run the desired command from cmd - it should stay open and you'll see an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you described in your example is setting up a Maven user name and password.  You'd only do that if you were publishing plugins to maven central or using a private repository so how you actually create the user name and password would be specific to your environment.  But once you have that you'll open up `~/.m2/settings.xml` in your favorite text editor and do something like the following:

```
<settings>
...
  <servers>
...
    <server>
      <id>your.server</id>
      <username>someUser</username>
      <password>{COQLCE6DU6GtcS5P=}</password>
    </server>
...
  </servers>
...
</settings>
```

You'll need to encrypt your password and mvn command can do that using the following:

```
mvn --encrypt-password <password>
```

Of course you'll have to install maven on your local system which can be done following instructions:

https://maven.apache.org/install.html

https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

As for using Groovy itself you'll want to install the groovy SDK before you can use it.  You can follow instructions here:

https://groovy-lang.org/install.html

Once you have all of that setup you'll restart your command prompt (ie cmd) so you can pick up `GROOVY_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` environment variables.  Then you can begin to run a groovy script.  But you can also run the groovy shell doing:

```
> groovysh
> println("Hello from Groovy!")
```

If you see it print `Hello from Groovy!` then you have installed a working installation of Groovy.